Имитация нажатия на кнопку в чате ВК, отправка Callback
Возникла сложность с имитацией "нажатия" callback-кнопки в ВК. Понятно, что "нажатия" нет, и происходит либо отправка текста, либо отправка Callback.
Обычные кнопки получается отправлять через функцию messages.send vk API.
Как отправить Callback?  Payload известен
